# How can I write a query that returns a row for every distinct value in one column and returns an arbitrary value from another column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, filter, duplicates

I'd like to find a, hopefully simple, solution to the following problem.

I have a table like this

```
Name -  GUID 

NameA   {AH42-AJG5-AFHA}      
NameA   {AJD4-AFJ4-HVFA}      
NameB   {BGA4-AJGA-GHAA}
NameB   {JGA8-GGK1-KLP9}      
NameA   {KGA4-JAD4-GJA9}
```

An example of my desired outcome is

```
NameA   {AH42-AJG5-AFHA} 
NameB   {BGA4-AJGA-GHAA}
```

I want exactly 1 entry for a specific name, and I need any GUID which was associated with this name in the second column.  (The GUID that is returned is arbitrary)

Thanks for your advice.

Comment: What RDBMS? How do you define which guid to return? Is it arbitrary? Also what is the datatype of `GUID` as they don't look like actual guids?

Comment: Given your sample, it means you want the lowest GUID in lexicographical order?

Comment: Which GUID do you want for a given name ?

Comment: it is arbitrary which guid will be selected. the datatypes of the guids in my table are Strings.

Comment: @user974631 - Reason for asking is that if you are on SQL Server you can't use `MIN` on a `uniqueidentifier` column but not relevant for this case then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming what GUID is returned is irrelevant; so long as it has an Associate to one of the names.

```
Select [name], min([GUID]) as mGuid
FROM tableLikeThis
Group by [Name]
```

Comment: it works but the query output is kinda weird = "<Name>checkDEC</Name><Expr1001>{09006050-90E3-46d8-965E-8151F0DA6215}</Expr1001>"  it should be "<Name>checkDEC</Name><GUID>{09006050-90E3-46d8-965E-8151F0DA6215}</GUID>" any ideas for that?

Comment: @user974631 - You need to give an alias to the column `min(GUID) AS GUID`.

Comment: Well name and GUID might both be reserved words.  The output as pasted looks like the query is returning an XML output.  Not sure why.

Comment: yeah actually it is. iam doing sql queries in the uml tool enterprise architect and it returns xml documents as the qry results.

Answer (score 0):

Just to mention an alternate way of doing it (xQbert already answered the question). You could do something along:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (Guid) Name, Guid  
FROM Table
```